# Can I specify Node.js command line options in AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-application-model

I'm using AWS SAM and running against Node 10.x.

Would love to pass in the flags for experimental modules and top level await.

Thanks!

Comment: I am interested in this too now. AWS Lambda is getting more proactive at supporting the latest versions of Node.js and being able to use "Harmony" flags at some point would be useful. Especially with Optional Chaining and Nullish Coalescing now supported Node 13 and Node 14 with --harmony-optional-chaining and --harmony-nullish.

Answer (score 5):

You can add Node.js command line options to lambda by setting the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable.

https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options

Comment: I tried doing this in template.yaml file, It didn't work for me.

`Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/stock-checker/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NODE_OPTIONS: "--experimental-modules"`